# Iterate over a singleton or multiple of a returned DataMapper class

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have the following code

```
if admin_authorized?
  @allschools = School.all
elsif faculty_authorized?
  @allschools = School.get(Faculty.get(session[:faculty_id]))
end
```

I am getting this error

```
undefined method `each' for #<School:0x007f88a1360318>
```

@allschools will either be an array of schools or a singleton school.  I need to iterate over this list in the view, like so:

```
<% @allschools.each do |s| %>
  <%= f_optionselected(s.id.to_s, params[:school], s.name) %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried to do if statements with @allschools.count, @allschools.typeof(Array), ....

Should I use two different variables and a PHP type isset() statment to determine which block to display?  Or is there a way to iterate over the statement in some Ruby way?

Answer (score 0):

`School.all` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation and you can iterate through it, as you do with `each`. I think `School.get` returns a single School instance, right? Try to wrap it into an Array:

```
@allschools = [School.get(Faculty.get(session[:faculty_id]))]
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct.  School.all returns as an array/hash and has .each method, while School.get only returns one record.  I'm still getting this error: undefined method `each' for #<School:0x007f88a1360318>

Comment: Your error indicates that you call `each` for a `School` instance. You are sure, you tried to put the single instance into an array? If you did, you should be able to iterate through it and to keep your view as it is.

Comment: I put your example code in and got that error code.  I know almost know ruby.